download pdf in flutter web from blob
I have this basic flutter app.
when running it on chrome and clicking on the download button, pdf is getting downloaded but it is not opening, it says 'Failed to load PDF document'
NOTE: if filename is 'sample.txt' then file is getting saved as txt and also getting opened with content 'ABCDE'
How can we open the content in pdf?
code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:html' as html;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('PDF Downloader'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: DownloadButton(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DownloadButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Uint8List pdfData = Uint8List.fromList([65, 66, 67, 68, 69]); // Sample Uint8List data

  void _downloadPdf(BuildContext context) {
    String filename = 'sample.pdf'; // Set the filename with appropriate extension
    String mimeType = 'application/pdf'; // Set the MIME type for PDF

    // Create a Blob from the Uint8List with the specified MIME type
    var blob = html.Blob([pdfData], mimeType);

    // Create an anchor element
    var anchor = html.AnchorElement(href: html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob))
      ..setAttribute("download", filename);

    // Trigger download by simulating click event
    anchor.click();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => _downloadPdf(context),
      child: Text('Download PDF'),
    );
  }
} 


The Uint8List you're creating contains only the ASCII codes for the letters 'ABCDE', which is not a valid PDF file.
To generate a valid PDF file, you need to create a PDF document using a library like pdf or syncfusion_flutter_pdf.
Here's an example using the pdf library:
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';

void _downloadPdf(BuildContext context) {
  String filename = 'sample.pdf';
  String mimeType = 'application/pdf';

  final pdfDoc = PWDocument();
  final page = pdfDoc.addPage();
  final text = PWText(
    text: 'Hello, World!',
    fontSize: 24,
  );
  page.add(text);

  // this will convert PDF document to a Uint8List
  final pdfData = pdfDoc.save();

  // creating  a Blob from the Uint8List with the specified MIME type
  var blob = html.Blob([pdfData], mimeType);

  // create an anchor element
  var anchor = html.AnchorElement(href: html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob))
    ..setAttribute("download", filename);

  // Download the pdf
  anchor.click();
}

This code will generate a valid pdf.

From the api I am getting Uint8List array, using that I need to create pdf, is it possible?

Yes, you can achieve this with that package.
I recommend using syncfusion_flutter_pdf package
